# How to parse iso8601 to eos time format?

Tags: smart-contract, c++

How does one parse an iso8601 string to eos time_point format?

Answer (score 2):

This example does not work:

```
void show(const std::string& time_str)
{
    const time_point& current_time = time_point::from_iso_string(time_str);
    print(current_time.elapsed._count);
}
```

`time_point::from_iso_string` was cut out from eos time_point. According to [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4922) issue one should not parse strings in smart contract at all. As instead, binary data should be used and passed to parameters for the sake of performance.

Comment: You should probably include this info as part of the question rather than an answer.

Comment: This is answering my own question, as it states, that one should not do such thing per devs recommendation.

Comment: I see I misread this.

Comment: If you really really need to do this I suggest you copy-paste old `from_iso_string` implementation from the Git history and use it as a private method in your code.